# What is the best strategy to commit the changes using the UnitOfWork pattern?

Tags: .net, design-patterns, unit-of-work

What is the best strategy to commit the changes using the UnitOfWork pattern? Doing it inside a try-catch? If I need to rollback , the catch is the best place to do it in that case?

```cs
public void Commit() {
            _context.SaveChanges();
}

public void Rollback() {
            _context
                .ChangeTracker
                .Entries()
                .Where(entry => entry.State != EntityState.Unchanged)
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(entry => {
                    switch (entry.State)
                    {
                        // Under the covers, changing the state of an entity from  
                        // Modified to Unchanged first sets the values of all  
                        // properties to the original values that were read from  
                        // the database when it was queried, and then marks the  
                        // entity as Unchanged. This will also reject changes to  
                        // FK relationships since the original value of the FK  
                        // will be restored. 
                        case EntityState.Modified:
                            entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                            break;
                        case EntityState.Added:
                            entry.State = EntityState.Detached;
                            break;
                        // If the EntityState is the Deleted, reload the date from the database.   
                        case EntityState.Deleted:
                            entry.Reload();
                            break;
                        default: break;
                    }
                });
}
```

```cs
try { 
  UnitOfWorkRPOMain.Commit();
} catch (Exception ex) {
  UnitOfWorkRPOMain.Rollback();
  Logger.Error(baseLog + "Error - ex.Message).");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The try/catch is fine. However, I'm going to suggest not wrapping the DbContext in a Unit of Work. Entity Framework already implements the Unit of Work and Repository patterns. Specifically, the DbContext is the Unit of Work and each DbSet is a repository.

With this in mind, your code may look something like this:

**sample**

```
using (var context = new YourContext())
{
    using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            // your code
            context.SaveChanges();
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
            // some logging
        }
    }
}
```

More info on transactions with EF:

https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/transaction-in-entity-framework.aspx

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/transactions